# Graphql Filter by query

Tags: graphql

So I'm trying to learn graphql I've been playing around with the [ENS subgraph on the graph](https://thegraph.com/explorer/subgraph/ensdomains/ens?selected=playground)

I've figured out how to do simple filtering but when I try to write more complex filters they do not compile.

I'm trying to get the top 5 transactions for the each of the top 5 domains.  (e.g for each domain I want the top 5 transactions)

```
{
  #Sample Query to get the first 5 domains (not needed for question but used to validate results)
  domains(first: 5) {
    id
    name
    labelName
    labelhash
  }

  #attempt to filter the transfer.domain.id by TOP 5 domains.id
  transfers(where: { domain { id: domains(first: 5) { id } } }) {
    id
    domain {
      id
    }
    blockNumber
    transactionID
  }
}
```

**EDIT**  I'm going to attempt to simplify my request since I'm not sure nesting queries is possible.  How can I filter an inner query by Id:

```
transfers(where: {domain.id: "0x9c0fc2519ae862cee27778e5c34714d6c7e3ca21ad572df47ad9f6fe530909bd"}) {
  id
  domain {
    id
  }
  blockNumber
  transactionID
}
```

**NOTE:** Domain.Id = does not compile how would I write a filtered query like that?

However, My filter doesn't compile syntactically.  How can I write a query which filters by a child property?

Comment: Doesn't the fact that the more complex filters are failing is in part due to the fact that there does not exist their **resolver** counterpart(s) on the server?

Comment: @ΩmegaMan sorry I'm very new to graphQL, to be honest I don't know if i'm even writing the query correctly.  I would think if graphql is a querying protocol that they would support nested queries but I could not find an example online, and alot of the tutorial seems to be using an older version

Answer (score 1):

You can query like this

```
query {
  getPost(id: "0x1") {
    title
    text
    datePublished
  }
}
```

Got this from https://dgraph.io/docs/graphql/queries/search-filtering/

Comment: Thanks, I'll consider manually constructing the expression.  However, I thought one of the main purposes of GraphQL is that it's suppose to limit round trips to the server by allowing you to obtain all of your data in a single query.  Doing multiple trips requires me to parse the response back from the server

Comment: This isn't really the answer, but I don't like bounties to go to waste so it's all yours.